# Need fix in my website chat plugin

Tags: php, plugins

I am using a chat plugin, but it is creating problems. Sometime it is slow and other times it is not responding. I have tried to ask for help but most of the times, answers are related to server, which I do not know, how does it related to? You can easily see 30 seconds delay in sending the message.

Website is [this](http://iguestblog.com) one.

Comment: SO isn't a free "fix my code / issues" service.

Comment: I have contacted the support team, but hasn't good any response from them.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a plugin settings, I assume that there are options where you can speed up the messages by reducing the polling time. Keep in mind that the faster you poll for new messages, the more resources it requires from your server. So if you find you are running into any server issues then you will want to increase it back up again or look into upgrading your server.
Hope that helps!